# Python inheritance, class level variables, __init__ takes no arguments

Tags: python

I tried some code like:

```
class StaticPageStage(StageBase):
    key = Segments.STATICPAGE
    _preprocessors = [FacebookGraphStage(), ]
    
    def __init__():
        pass
    
    def process(self, data):
        data = self._preprocess(data)
        return self.handle_results(tuple(x for x in data))
```

but I get an exception that says `TypeError: __init__() takes no arguments (1 given)`. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I was about to change the title of your question, as your problem is not related to it, but I wanted to avoid being too invasive as I should have to completely rephrase it.. Please change it by yourself. :)

Comment: I'm juggling a bunch of syntaxes lately. Silly mistake.

Comment: Anybody know of a similar question to tag as duplicate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the default `self` parameter to `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 3):

**init** must have at least one argument in its signature:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Here the error comes probably from FacebookGraphStage. Check its **init** method (and the other ones in your files) to solve the problem

Comment: Not just `__init__`, but *every* function within a `class` deceleration.

Comment: Not every. You can have static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You *always* use the `self` argument within function definitions inside of classes, even if the function never takes in a parameter. `self` is passed to all of the functions as a first parameter, so the error is saying that your function `__init__` isn't accepting it.

Here's some (hopefully) working code:

```
class StageBase(object):
    key = Segments.NONE
    _preprocessors = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.closing = False
        self.working = False
        self._que = None
        self._working_lock = None
        self._que_lock = None

    #whole bunch of other methods


class StaticPageStage(StageBase):
    key = Segments.STATICPAGE
    _preprocessors = [FacebookGraphStage(), ]

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, data):
        data = self._preprocess(data)
        return self.handle_results(tuple(x for x in data))
```